# How to show wifi password?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, wifi-password

I have a rooted Samsung s3 mini, android version 4.1.2

How to show the saved wifi password of the router I am connected to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From any file manager that allows root access to system files you can go into `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file or directly search for `wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

You can open it with any text editor.

If you have Terminal Emulator you can also do this:

```
cat /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

You will find all your saved passwords inside that file. Password will be stored as:

```
network={
    ssid="WiFiName"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=1
}
```

Comment: One more thing do I need to root my device in order to do that or it do works with unrooted device too ? as I can't find anything inside /data folder.

Comment: You would get permission denied of you would need root access and not have it. I can't answer your question direcy, but it might be that you are using different version of android which keeps the file in a different place. If you provide more details on your device and OS I might help you.

Comment: I am currently running Samsung Stock 4.1.2 Jellybean ROM over tab2. I have tried looking over the /data folder but the specified misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf file isn't there !

Comment: are the directories there? You can try to run this command to find it: `find /data -name "wpa_supplicant.conf"` or even `find / -name "wpa_supplicant.conf"` Anyway, I am pretty sure now that you need a rooted device.

Comment: Well, @edvinas.me I have tried searching for -name"wpa_supplicant.conf" under data file but can't find it in the data folder instead of it has something else like log.txt and com.onelou....oneweather . I guess device needs to be rooted any way thanks though !

Comment: It's easily to view your password, use this awesome app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ihnel.com.wifipassrecovery
Now you can:
- View your connected wifi passwords
- Backup/restore easily
- Share passwords with your friends
- This is FREE APP.

Answer (score 3):

You can also download the app "[Wifi Key Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.wifiKeyRecovery)" which is a lot easier.

Comment: The thing is I don't like giving root access to apps unless I really need them, but  thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: Worked perfectly! For some reason the text file wasn't in the path the other user suggested